# How to load XY coordinates of binary outline saved as tiff file?

Tags: r, image, imagej

I'm using the R package `Momocs` to compare outlines of shapes I've traced in ImageJ and saved as binary image tiffs.  For example: [one outline of snail teeth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFTxu.png).  Momocs requires a matrix of X and Y coordinates, and I'm having trouble converting from image to coordinates.

On the one hand: ImageJ has an option to Save As... XY Coordinates, but this only works on a selection.  I can use the wand tool to select the outline, but it encircles the one-pixel-wide outlines, e.g. a straight line would have coordinates of a long rectangle, describing both sides of the line.  This makes me see my snail teeth in [double-vision (image example of one tooth close-up)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m33N.png) and may adversely affect analysis.

On the other hand: Momocs has an `import_jpg1` command, but when I convert my images to jpegs (or make jpegs from scratch), they end up with light-colored pixels as noise around the outlines.  I tried the packages `tiff` and `rtiff`, but their outputs are not XY coordinates of the black parts of the tiff, and I'm not familiar enough with the outputs to understand how I might convert them to XY coordinates.

Can anyone help me do one (or multiple!) of these things:

- Upload tiffs to R in a format `Momocs` can read
- Convert tiff data uploaded via `tiff` or `rtiff` into a format
  `Momocs` can read
- Get a matrix of the XY coordinates of all black pixels in a
  binary-image tiff
- Convert a binary-image tiff to a binary-image jpeg

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily extract the matrix of XY coordinates of pixels meeting certain criteria with R's function `which` by specifying `arr.ind=TRUE`. To illustrate this approach I use the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) package *[EBImage](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/EBImage)* to directly load the sample PNG file from the provided URL. `readImage` is a wrapper for the functions provided in R packages *jpeg*, *png* and *tiff*, so apart from PNGs it also opens JPEG and TIFF files.

```
### Install EBImage
# source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
# biocLite("EBImage")

img <- EBImage::readImage("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFTxu.png")

mat <- which(img==0, arr.ind=TRUE, useNames=FALSE)
head(mat)

##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]  121   53
## [2,]  120   54
## [3,]  118   55
## [4,]  119   55
## [5,]  117   56
## [6,]  116   57
```

*EBImage* offers a wide range of tools for working with image data in R which might be of interest to you, such as functions for manipulating, filtering and displaying images. See the package [vignette](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/EBImage/inst/doc/EBImage-introduction.html) for an overview.